# Timer Object Windows App

Tags: c#, timer, windows-store-apps

I read a separate article here that explained how to make a simple text animation in a windows form application.  The Code below worked perfectly in a form.  However, I am creating a Windows Store App and it does not work.  The timer class is not recognized, and because of this, the code does not work.  Do I need to make a timer class, or is there some other class that I should use?  If I need to make a timer class, how would I do that?  Thank you.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 40;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    string stuff = "This is some text that looks like it is being typed.";
    int pos = 0;
    Timer t;



    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pos < stuff.Length)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(stuff.Substring(pos, 1));
            ++pos;
        }
        else
        {
            t.Stop();
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos = 0;
        textBox1.Clear();
        t.Start();
    }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The WinForms `Timer` isn't available in Windows Store Apps. You can use [`DispatcherTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead.

```
dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e) {

}
```

Comment: The above code was accepted by the compiler.  However, I am not sure what to do next.  I tried placing the contents of the if and else statement in the dispatcherTimer_Tick method, but the compiler did not accept ".AppendText".  I tried using ".Text", but that creates an animation that shows one letter at a time.  I would like to make the animation look like it is typing, with letters continually being added to the textblock.  Thank you for responding to my question.